# Redis 3 Waiting for the cluster to join

Tags: redis, ubuntu-16.04, redis-cluster

So i'm trying to create a cluster using the default redis guide.

but when running `ruby /usr/share/doc/redis-tools/examples/redis-trib.rb create ....` i get stuck forever in "Waiting for the cluster to join".

- Each redis conf is bound to their respective static ip address (Not only 127)
- My nodes are all located on an separate instance of ubuntu 16.04 in a Exsi envoirment without ANY firewall between them.
- Each host is not created separatly, I just copied the first and changed hostnames + static iface for the other two, if that could cause something?
- Master-slave replication works, so i doubt there is an connection issue?

Here is a print, if that can help in some way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mactW.jpg

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I have checked all hosts from another physical interface and I have connected to them successfully with `cluster-enabled no`

Both `6379` and `16379` are accepting connections on both 127.0.0.1 and 192....

And all hosts can reach each other with `telnet <host> <16379>`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: Sadly no. I asked on 3 different forums (Google hangouts and Reddit) with 0 answers. What i did instead was to configure master-slave(s) with redis sentinel instead...

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep only one IP in "bind " configuration directive in  `/etc/redis/redis.conf`  or even comment it out

I had same problem when there was following string in my config :

```
bind 127.0.0.1 172.19.2.10Х
```

Removed  `loopback`  interface on all the nodes and passed that obstacle.

Comment: That doesn't help. One trick I've heard of too is to swap both IP addresses, which also didn't help me. I'm on Redis 4, though.